# DataTable(s) Merge Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I have two datatables which I want to merge.

I know there are a lot of methods `2 for loops` and `dataset merge` and `linq`.

But I found out all of them needs to know exactly how many columns that each datatable has.

My case is a little bit different.

I am grabbing the data from 2 csv files and fill two datatables.

So, I don't know exactly how many columns do each of the databale have.

All I know is that each table has "NRIC" column which is unique.

Now, I want to merge them.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just do '.count' and find out how many columns you have?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you get the column names and/or number of columns by iterating through the Columns property of each of the DataTables?

The following link may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx

Comment: I'd prefer to do all of it in one go.. like linq query style.. if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try like the below one.Here location is common entity between two tables.

var results = t1.AsEnumerable().Join(t2.AsEnumerable(),
                a => a.Field<String>("Location"),
                b => b.Field<String>("Location"),
                (a, b) =>
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = a.ItemArray.Concat(b.ItemArray).ToArray();
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                    return row;
                });
```